# Is there a way to read a string faster than getchar() (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, input

I am participating in some programming competitions, and on many problems there's the need to read strings from an input file. Obviously performance is a big issue on those competitions, and strings might be huge, so I am trying to understand the most efficient way to read those strings.

My guess is that reading the strings char by char, with getchar(), is the fastest you can go. That's because even if you use other functions, say fgets() or getline(), those functions will still need to read every char anyway.

**Update**: I know that I/O won't be a bottleneck on most algorithmic problems. That being said I would still very much like to know what's the fastest way you can use to read strings, should this become an issue on any future problem.

Comment: How about using good old c++ streams?

Comment: The way programming competition questions are designed, I/O will not plausibly be the bottleneck. If you're timing out it's because your algorithm for the actual work isn't clever enough.

Comment: @Kari Knechtel, I agree with that. That being said since I need to read input anyway I'd rather do it the most efficient way and not worry about whether I can improve it or not later on.

Comment: You are missing something. `getchar()` means that you pay the price of a function call for each char. As others have said, I/O probably won't be the bottleneck, but it might just be in your program if you read the input char by char with `getchar()`.

Comment: @Complicated see bio, that's exactly what I am asking. So what would you rather use, scanf()?, fgets()? std::cin ?

Comment: @DanielS: If you use `std::ostream::read()`, then it is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::istream::read()` function to read a chunk of unformatted data. It is relatively faster precisely because the data is *unformatted*. All overloads of `operator>>` read *formatted* data which makes reading from stream slower compared to `read()`.

Similarly, you can use `std::ostream::write()` function to write a chunk of data to output stream at once.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse is true, reading larger chunks of data into memory in one go is far faster than reading one character at a time.  The OS and/or hard drive will likley cache the data in any case, but the function call overhead alone of repeatedly cycling through the standard-library, OS, file system and device driver for each character is significant for large data sets.

When handling strings there are some more important performance issues you might consider: [*Back to Basics* by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Either way, the most convincing way to answer the question for yourself is to write test code that investigates the difference between different I/O methods.

Comment: In addition, on some platforms each stdio call takes a lock, which further adds to the cost of byte-by-byte IO.